# Why do I get warning: Class 'Iterable' does not define '__getitem__'...?

Tags: python, list, pycharm, iterable

I have a function whose purpose is to take either an iterable or a singleton `x` and a parameter `num_nodes`, and:

- If x is a singleton, return a list consisting of `num_nodes` copies of `x`.
- If x is a list of length `num_nodes`, return `x`.
- Otherwise, raise a ValueError.

The function code (updated):

```
def ensure_list_for_nodes(x, num_nodes, default=None):
    # Is x None?
    if x is None:
        return [default] * num_nodes
    else:
        # Determine whether x is singleton or iterable.
        if is_iterable(x):
            if len(list(x)) == num_nodes:
                return list(x)
            else:
                raise ValueError('x must be a singleton or a list of length num_nodes')
        else:
            return [x] * num_nodes
```

Note that the function returns a list in any case (or raises an error).

Here is the code for `is_iterable()` (updated):

```
def is_iterable(x):
    # First check whether x is a string (because strings act like iterables).
    if isinstance(x, str):
        return False
    else:
        try:
            _ = iter(x)
        except TypeError:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Then I call the function:

```
my_list = ensure_list_for_nodes(5, 3)
print(my_list[0])
```

And PyCharm gives me a warning on the `[` in `my_list[0]`:

```
Class 'Iterable' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances
```

It seems that PyCharm realizes that my function returns an iterable, but not that the iterable is always a list. What's going wrong here, and how can I fix it?

(Note that the function seems to work correctly. I'm just bothered by the warning.)

Comment: Can you provide `is_iterable`? depending on what it does `len(x)` might cause a TypeError

Comment: if `x == iter("foo") ` then `len(x)` raises `TypeError: object of type 'str_iterator' has no len()`. either you should check for a sequence instead of an iterable, or you can't rely on len without first constructing a known sequence such as a list (`len(list(x)) == 3`).

Comment: The code you show doesn't reproduce your error. `ensure_list_for_nodes(5, 3)` returns `[5, 5, 5]`, and `my_list[0]` returns `5`. Either there is more relevant code you aren't showing (what is the class `Iterable` referred to by the error?), or this is a PyCharm issue unrelated to Python.

Comment: OT: That definition of `is_iterable` cannot be used on many iterators (such as generators) because it uses up all the items. Better is to try [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#iter) and catch failure.

Comment: I have updated `ensure_list_for_nodes()` per @steviestickman's suggestion and `is_iterable()` per @rici's suggestion. The issue persists.

Comment: @chepner There is no error -- it is only a warning issued by PyCharm. I agree this is a PyCharm issue and not a general Python issue.

Comment: @chepner I did not define the class `Iterable`. That's part of my question -- I don't understand why PyCharm is interpreting the return value of my function as an `Iterable` as opposed to a list.

Comment: My impression of PyCharm (unfair and biased, probably, given that it is formed entirely from questions like this on Stack Overflow) is that it tries to be far too smart, and ends up causing more problems than it solves.